Existing chroma Vector DB not getting deleted
I'm creating a project where a user uploads a PDF, which creates a chroma vector db, and the user receives the output. The issue arises when the user uploads a second PDF: the system should delete the existing vector db and create a new one. However, I keep running into a 'PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' error. It appears that the file is still in use by another process, and I’m unable to delete the old vector db as needed. How can I resolve this issue to ensure the file is properly closed or released before deletion?
After researching, I found that Chroma doesn't have a built-in function to close or delete the vector db. I’ve tried several solutions, including force deletion and using the psutil library to terminate processes, but none have worked so far. It would be really helpful if anyone could help me on this.
This is the code below:
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = FastAPI()

# Folders
OUTPUT_DIR = "output_dir"
PERSIST_DIR = "vector_db"

os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(PERSIST_DIR, exist_ok=True)

OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

# 
def process_pdf(pdf_path: str) -> str:
    # Check if a vector DB already exists, and delete it if found
    if os.path.exists(PERSIST_DIR):
        shutil.rmtree(PERSIST_DIR)
        os.makedirs(PERSIST_DIR)

    # Load the PDF document
    loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_path)
    pages = loader.load()

    # Split the document into chunks
    splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size=200,  
        chunk_overlap=50  
    )
    chunks = splitter.split_documents(pages)

    # Initialize embeddings and vector store
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embeddings, persist_directory=PERSIST_DIR)

    # Initialize retriever and LLM
    retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1})
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        model="gpt-4o",
        temperature=0.9,
        max_tokens=500,
        openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
    )

    # Create prompt template and retrieval chain
    template = """
    Act as an experienced document reviewer. Your task is to give a clear concise summary of the                 document.
    context: {context}
    input: {input}
    answer:
    """
    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)
    combine_docs_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)
    retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, combine_docs_chain)

    # Generate responses from the LLM
    response_1 = retrieval_chain.invoke({"input": "Give me summary of the document."})
    time.sleep(5)

    # Generate a unique filename by incrementing a number suffix
    base_filename = "Output"
    file_number = 1

    while os.path.exists(f"{OUTPUT_DIR}/{base_filename}_{file_number}.txt"):
        file_number += 1

    filename = f"{OUTPUT_DIR}/{base_filename}_{file_number}.txt"
    
    # Save responses to a text file 
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("Output:\n\n")

        file.write("Summary:\n")
        file.write(response_1["answer"] + "\n\n")
    return filename  


# API
@app.post("/process-pdf/")
async def process_pdf_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        # Use a temporary directory to store the uploaded PDF file
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            temp_pdf_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file.filename)

            # Save the uploaded PDF temporarily
            with open(temp_pdf_path, "wb") as temp_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, temp_file)

            # Process the PDF and generate the report
            result_file_path = process_pdf(temp_pdf_path)

        # Return the generated text file as a response
        return FileResponse(result_file_path, filename=os.path.basename(result_file_path))

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


Add the [python] tag. This will properly highlight your code

Well you could use different collections instead of different vector db's.
